# Inserting values left to right in a binary search tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, binary

What does it mean to build a binary search tree by inserting values from left to right starting from an empty tree? The "left to right" part confuses me..I know how to build one by normally inserting values from the top..but what does this mean?

Could anyone please explain how to insert values from left to right with an example? An example would be really helpful..please and thank you.

Comment: Is this a `complete` and/or `balanced` binary tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume "left to right" refers to the order of processing a given key sequence.

E.g. given the key sequence $[1, 5, 2, 3]$, You just start with an empty tree and insert $1$, then $5$, then $2$ and at last $3$.

Other orderings include "in random order" and "in reversed order (or right to left)".